# netBeans conflict with java command prompt

Tags: java, netbeans

I use this code in netBeans , it's compilation error .

```
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int a2[]={2,3},a3={4,5,3},a4={1,2,3,4};
int a1[][]={a2,a3,a4};
System.out.println(a1[0][1]+","+a1[1][2]+","+a1[2][3]);
}}
```

the I use the command prompt , and that's not occurred any error .. 
and I obtained this output

> 3,3,4

Comment: _it's compilation error_ what error NetBeans shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a3` and `a4` both variable must be declared as array `[]` like `a3[]` and `a4[]`.

```
int a2[]={2,3},a4[]={1,2,3,4}, a3[]={4,5,3};
```

Comment: I know how to make it without error , but I just want to know why it is compile in command prompt but not compile it netBeans .

Comment: It is not compiling even in command prompt. Compilation error - `illegal initializer for int` compiled in jre 6.

Answer (score 0):

I try to compile your program in my system, and i got following result

[image]

change code like following then there will be no error

```
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int a2[]={2,3},a3[]={4,5,3},a4[]={1,2,3,4};
int a1[][]={ a2,a3,a4 };
System.out.println(a1[0][1]+","+a1[1][2]+","+a1[2][3]);
}}
```

Comment: I know how to make it without error , but I just want to know why it is compile in command prompt but not compile it netBeans .

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
public class Main
{   public static void main(String[] args)
    {   int[] a2={2,3},a3={4,5,3},a4={1,2,3,4};
        int a1[][]={a2,a3,a4};
        System.out.println(a1[0][1]+","+a1[1][2]+","+a1[2][3]);
    }
}
```

is different from this code:

```
public class Main
{   public static void main(String[] args)
    {   int a2[]={2,3},a3={4,5,3},a4={1,2,3,4};
        int a1[][]={a2,a3,a4};
        System.out.println(a1[0][1]+","+a1[1][2]+","+a1[2][3]);
    }
}
```

If you look at line number 3 in each code.

In the first code `int[] a2={2,3},a3=...` indicates that `a2` is an integer array, and `a3` is also an integer array.

In the second code `int a2[]={2,3},a3=...` indicates that variable a3 is an integer and each element of array `a2` is an integer.

Looks like, you must have run first code on command line & second code in netbeans.